# responsive iframe in responsive html website

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

i am trying to make an iframe responsive, in order to be correctly viewed on mobile devices etc, and what i am doing, although it is working good on mobile devices, it ruins the iframe on normal displays.

the iframe is that

```
<div class="conti" align="center" >
<iframe id="extFrame" src="html5/Project1.html" height="600px" width=" 800px"></iframe>
</div>
```

and the css style is

```
<style>
.conti {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.conti iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

that above makes the iframe full width but i want it 800*600.
any help?

Comment: you declare iframe properties inline (height="600px" width=" 800px") and at the same time in css ( width: 100%; height: 100%;) ? please make your mind

Comment: my problem is not exactly on how to make it. but what i did wrong. Anyway it is kind of duplicate you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete witdh and height properties defined on css styles and the iframe will be generated with your desired dimensions.

I hope it helps. But are you just giving one size for every device? This is not responsive at all... You have to add some media queries.

This is a good post with different media queries for Responsive Design:

[Media Queries for Responsive Design](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want it 800x600 then say you want it 800x600 instead of 100%x100%.

```
width: 800px;
height: 600px;
```